# How to fill-in two input[text] in an HTML form using a barcode reader?

Tags: html, webforms, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a web page with one `input text` for the barcode content and a `select` for the barcode type.

So using the database, it is possible to generate the barcode in the good format.

A normal final user don't know which barcode as which type, but the barcode reader knows and can send this type as a keyboard input.

The problem is that I don't know how to change from the input to the select.

If I use, the `\t`, it prints a tabulation in the input instead of switching from a input to the other. If I use a `\n` it submit the form.

Do you have any idea of how I can do it so that my form can be use with or without the barcode reader?

It could print the barcode followed with the barcode type `6931442700194|EAN13` and split the content when processing the form but is there another solution?

Comment: can you give a sample output of the barcode reader?

Comment: I can define the output I need. Basicaly, there is two variables : `symbol.data` and `symbol.type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some Javascript and the [onchange event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) (or some similar event) to detect the value of your `input text` has been changed (by your barcode reader). Then you get this value and split it over your `input text` and `select`.

```
<input type='text' id='inputtext' onchange='splitValue();' />
<select id='myselect'>...</select>
```

And the JavaScript

```
function splitValue()
{
    var input=document.getElementById('inputtext');
    var select=document.getElementById('myselect');
    var test = input.value;

    // Perform some splitting and formatting

    input.value = splitted_inputvalue;
    select.value = splitted_selectvalue;
}
```